# A computation modulo 1223

Tags: number-theory

I want to compute $48^{306}$ modulo $1223$. I can't use a calculator, hence I tried to simplify something.

I have $306=2^8+2^5+2^4+2$, thus $48^{306}=48^{2^8+2^5+2^4+2}=48^{2^8}\cdot 48^{2^5}\cdot 48^{2^4}\cdot 48^2\pmod{1223}$

Is there any trick to speed up the computation?

Comment: Note $306*4-1=1223$ and that $1223$ is prime.

Comment: If you follow my suggestion, you will be left with a modular quadratic with solutions $\pm464$. The problem is to choose the correct one

Comment: @chubakueno I can't see how did you find $\pm 464$

Comment: But since $306$ is even, then note that by kegendre symbol $-464$ is not a quadratic residue

Comment: $(5)$ of http://www.mat.unimi.it/users/molteni/didattica/matematica/number_theory/exercise_sheet_6.pdf

Comment: Repeated squaring is a fine approach. What you have here requires only 12 multiplications... not so bad.

Comment: Without a calculator it's not entirely trivial to check that
$1223$ is prime.  If you recognize that $1225=35^2$ then
any prime factor must be $\pm 1 \bmod 8$, which leaves only
$7$, $17$, $23$, and $31$ to trial-divide, and that's not
too hard (esp. with tricks like $1223 = 1200 + 23 \not\equiv 0 \bmod 23$
and likewise $40 \cdot 31 = 1240$ so $1223 \not\equiv 0 \bmod 31$).
But then you still have to play with Fermat's little theorem and
quadratic reciprocity to get the solution.